# Extracting outermost points from irregular grid of points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, convex-hull

I am using ArcMap 9.3, and would like to remove all points inside an irregularly placed grid, except the outermost (boundary) points. For example, I would like to keep the black dots, while removing the gray dots. I have over a million points, therefore manually editing the shapefile won't be very efficient.

Can I get any pointers/suggestions?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a one-dimensional (X axis only) implementation of a convex hull.  Would it suffice to construct envelopes that span the X axis and walk in the Y dimension, and for each band, identify the points with minimum and maximum X values?

Comment: I think you will have to define the tolerance for "outside" points.  For example, if you reduce the size the displayed points it will become apparent that more of the points could be defined as "outside"--it is just a matter of how deep you go.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of +/- 10m from a convex hull boundary.

Comment: @Aaron, @Vince; thanks for the suggestions. Aaron, I did not ask the question clearly enough, but the size of the points won't alter much, cause I just need the the max and min X-axis values for every Y-Axis incremental step. The convex hull sounds promising and I will give it a try. Thanks for the suggestions